# I am not able to append labels to my training data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

When I append my labels I end up with 20580 for the length of y when what I'm hoping to do is end up with 120 which is the number of categories. How can I append the categories to my labels?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random as rand
import time

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

DATADIR = "C:/Users/samue/Documents/Datasets/DogBreeds/images/Images"
CATEGORIES = os.listdir("C:/Users/samue/Documents/Datasets/DogBreeds/images/Images")

IMG_SIZE = 100

training_data = []



def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
create_training_data()

rand.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y = np.array(y).reshape(-1,)

print(len(CATEGORIES))
print(len(X))
print(len(y))
```

The outputs I get at the end are:
120
20580
20580

Comment: By the look of it you have *20,580* data points, there should be the same number of elements in `X` (the input array) and `y` (the target array). Why are you expecting `y` to only have *120* elements?

Comment: Okay, I'll explain what I think is supposed to happen, maybe I have a complete misunderstanding of features and labels.

I'm trying to build a machine learning model. From what I understand the features (X) are your data points or photos in this case, and the labels (y) are the different groups you want to put data points into. So if my data set has 120 categories I would need 120 labels to correspond.

is that how it works?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should step back a little from the implementation details or even this specific problem to try to understand what is going on. In image classification, the objective is to classify the input, a *2D* or - *3D* tensor if it's multichannel image - by assigning it to a label. The number of labels is *finite*, you can only classify into a certain number of class.

To give an example, let's take the [`MNIST`](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) database. It is a well known *dummy*-dataset used for image classification tasks. In the training set, there are 60,000 `1x28x28`-images representing handwritten digits. Generally speaking, the goal with this dataset is to classify properly each image to a total of *10* labels. The labels correspond to numbers *"0"*, *"1"*, *"2"*, ..., and so on until *"9"*. So the question in this particular case is given image X, my model needs to predict a class for this image: either *"0"*, *"1"*, ..., or *"9"*, there are only *10* possibilities. In supervised learning, we use labels to train the model. For any given input, we need to know the *ground-truth* i.e. the real class this input belongs to. So in turn you end up with as many inputs as there are labels: because each one is assigned it's own label, regardless of the number of unique possible labels.

In your use case, it seems you are working with a total of *120* classes and *20,580* images. That's `20,580` unique data inputs. Remember, we need to have, for each one of those images, a corresponding *ground-truth*: the real class this image belongs to. So naturally you would end up with a total of *20,580* labels as well.

This might have been the source of your confusion: in my own terms `label` is different to `class`. A class set is a unique set of entities (animals, digits, ...) while a label refers to a particular class inside a class set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused. You should have a data set consisting of 120 classes.
For each of those classes you need to have images characteristic of that class. For example assume you are building a classifier to distinguish between images of dogs and images of cats. So you have 2 classes. You can structure your directories as follows

```
source_dir
----------cats_dir
------------------cats first image
------------------cats second images

------------------cats nth image

----------dogs_dir
------------------dogs first image
------------------dogs second image

------------------dogs m th image
```

For your case you will have 120 sub directories (class directories) below the  source_dir and each of these should contain images associated with class. In your case it would appear that you have a total of 20580 images. If they are evenly distributed you have roughly 171 images for each class. Now you want to use these images to train a CNN. You can do it the way you were proceeding however  I recommend against it because you will end up putting all 20580 100 X 100 images into memory all at once. This will take a very big memory and you are likely to get an OOM (out of memory) error. The way you solve that is to feed the data to your model in batches. For example 32 images at a time. Now Keras has useful functions to assist you in doing that. If you have the directory structure as shown above you can use the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to feed your images to the model in batches. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) This function also enables you to use image augmentation to help expand the diversity of your data set. Below is the code I recommend for the example of dog/cat classification I mentioned above.

```
source_dir-r'c:\temp\cats_and_dogs'
v_split=.2 # set this to determine the percentage of data to allocate to the validation set
data_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255,validation_split=v_split)
train_gen=data_gen.flow_from_directory(source_dir, target_size=(100,100),
                                       class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32,
                                       subset='training', color_mode='grayscale)
valid_gen=data_gen.flow_from_directory(source_dir, target_size=(100,100),
                                       class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32,
                                       subset='validation', color_mode='grayscale, shuffle=False)
```

when you compile your model set loss='categorical_crossentropy'.
you can use the two generators above as inputs to model.fit